# Qt File not found using component

Tags: c++, qt

C++:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlEngine engine;
    interaction inter("test");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("interaction", &inter);
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("qrc:///main.qml"));
    if (component.status() != component.Ready) {
        if (component.status() == component.Error) {
             qDebug(component.errorString().toUtf8().constData());
        }
    }
    else {
    qDebug("not ready");
    }
}
component.create();

return app.exec();
}
```

QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    width: 500 ; height: 500
    visible: true
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
           text.text = inter.author
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: text
        text: "some text to change"
    }
}
```

error:

"file:///C:/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/build-testcpp-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_OpenGL_64bit-Debug/qrc:/main.qml:-1 File not found

QQmlComponent: Component is not ready"

I am new to qt and trying to use c++ to change a text element, it compiles and runs fine but it never loads because it cannot find the qrc file. I have tried disabling shadow builds, passing a QUrl with the full path instead of "qrc:///main.qml" and I've tried wrapping the path in QStringLiteral but nothing seems to work.

If anyone has any advice it would be appreciated thanks.

edit:

.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick

SOURCES += main.cpp \
interaction.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)

HEADERS += \
interaction.h
```

.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>MyItem.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't disable shadow builds. They are not the problem. Not ever.

The `qrc` doesn't refer to the file system. It refers to the Qt resource system. The `main.qml` file must be compiled into your application's executable. The qt resource compiler (qrc) tool handles that.

Thus, your URL is wrong. The file is *not* a local file. It is a resource. Simply do:

```
QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! included .pro and the .qrc in the original question, yea I usually wouldn't mess with the project config but I was trying anything I could find.